# Handling same variable in traits

Tags: scala, traits

If I write something like this:

```
trait foo {
    val a: Int
}

trait bar extends foo{
    val a:Int
}

case class baz(fish:Int) extends bar {
   val a = 3
 }
```

why does not it throw any compilation error? I assume if there are two variables of the same name, an error should get thrown but the code works smoothly. And which value of 'a' gets updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val a: Int` in both trait `foo` and `bar` are the same. When `bar` extends `foo`, you must define a value for `a` or leave it abstract.

In your example, you are explicitly leaving `a` as abstract. This would have the same effect:

```
trait foo {
    val a: Int
}

trait bar extends foo

case class baz(fish:Int) extends bar {
    val a = 3
}
```